# Overwrite 'hover' when another specific class is included

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-link-dark">
  <i class="material-icons">help</i>
</button>
```

When I hover over it, it becomes blue. I want to alter this.

This does the trick:

```
  .btn-link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
```

But I only want this when the class `btn-link-dark` is included.
These syntax, used seperate, don't work:

```
  .btn-link-dark .btn-link:hover {
    color: white;
  }

  .btn-link-dark:hover .btn-link:hover {
    color: white;
  }
```

I don't want a third class.

Comment: your only fault was that you have this space between hover .btn-link remove it as in the 2 answers and it will work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting a space between the classes, you're using the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

```
.btn-link-dark .btn-link
```

translates to "A `.btn-link` which is a descendant of a `.btn-link-dark`". To indicate that one element needs both class names, don't put a space between them, eg `.btn-link-dark.btn-link:hover`:

```css
.btn-link-dark.btn-link:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-link-dark">
  <i class="material-icons">help (hover effect)</i>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
  <i class="material-icons">help (no effect)</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override using **`!important;`**

This approach can be used if you want to override existing hover styles with your styles.

```css
 .btn-link-dark.btn-link:hover {
    color: red;
  }

  .btn-link-dark.btn-link:hover {
    color: green !important;
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-link-dark">
  <i class="material-icons">help</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .btn-link.btn-link-dark:hover {
    color: blue;
  }

  .btn-link:hover {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-link-dark">
  <i class="material-icons">help</i>
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/aq9Laaew/158765/

This works fine.